# No Group Policy snap-in available to be added in Microsoft Management Console (Win11 Pro)

Tags: windows, windows-11, group-policy

When I go to "Edit group policy" on Win11 Pro, it gives me this error:
[image: MMC Error]

Add or Remove Snap-ins option in Microsoft Management Console does not show any Group Policy option to snap-in

[image: MMC Snap-in]

This is a new Windows 11 Pro install, and I have the latest Windows Updates installed on the stable channel.

[image: Win Version]

Comment: It says Windows 11 Pro. So gpedit should be there (is on Pro machines).  Do a Windows 11 Repair Install to correct your system.

Comment: What happens when you press Win+R and type `gpedit.msc`?

Comment: @John you are right, after fresh installing Windows, everything is working well. The "System Preparation Tool" was used by the computer reseller, which could be a bad image they are using perhaps? Anyway, thank you for the advice... if you add it as an answer, I can accept it

Comment: I posted an answer for you @Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It says Windows 11 Pro. So gpedit should be there (is on Pro
> machines). .....  Certainly all is well on my own Window 11 Pro machines here.

Two approaches here:

**(1) Do a Windows 11 Repair Install:**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

> Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Download.  Run the downloaded file  (double click
> on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB
> Key. Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.   Proceed
> normally answering the prompts.  The default Keep prompt is to **Keep
> Everything**.

**(2) Do a fresh install of Windows 11.**

This may be possibly just as easy. It may be that the original image was defective, or if somehow the Windows User Profile was damaged. In either case, then, this is what you must do.